# Json reader with different type in an array

Tags: java, arrays, json, scala, playframework

I would like to write a Json reader for such Json

```
    {
        "headers": [
            {
                "id": "time:monthly",
                "type": "a"
            },
            {
                "id": "Value1",
                "type": "b"
            },
            {
                "id": "Value2",
                "type": "b"
            }
        ],
        "rows": [
            [
                "2013-01",
                4,
                5
            ],
            [
                "2013-02",
                3,
                6
            ]
        ]
    }
```

I know (thanks to the header) that in the elements of rows the first element is of a type `a`, the second and the third will be of type `b`. My goal is to create an object row `(List[a],List[b])` (
the number of element of type a and b varies that's why I use `List`).
My question is how can I parse rows or how can I read a Json array with different type of object and without an id ?

Comment: I've tried the JSON on http://jsonlint.com, and it seems to be invalid. Can you fix it? Thanks.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: `rows` part of your json string is not a valid json.

Comment: just add closing square bracket at the line before last (so it becomes two closing square brackets)

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to setup the model with cases classes and mix the play framework macro base json reader with a custom one for your rows like this.

```
    import play.api.libs.json._

    case class Header(id: String, `type`: String)
    case class Row(a: String, b: Int, c: Int)
    case class Data(headers: Seq[Header], rows: Seq[Row])

    object RowReads extends Reads[Row] {
      def reads(js: JsValue) = js match {
        case JsArray(Seq(a,b,c)) =>
          (a,b,c) match {
            case (a: JsString, b: JsNumber, c: JsNumber) =>
              JsSuccess(Row(a.value,b.value.toInt,c.value.toInt))
            case _ => JsError("nope")
          }
          case _ => JsError("nope")
      }
    }

    object Formats {
      implicit val headerReads = Json.reads[Header]
      implicit val rowReads = RowReads
      implicit val dataReads = Json.reads[Data]

      def readIt(js: JsValue) = {
        Json.fromJson[Data](js: JsValue)
      }
    }
```

For more details.
https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJson